React Native Build Error: Multiple Devices Connected and Path Issues
I'm facing multiple errors when trying to run a React Native app cloned from GitHub on either my physical device (Redmi Note 9 Pro Max) or an emulator (Pixel_3a_API_33_x86_64). Here are the issues based on the command executed:

When running with a specific device ID (npx react-native run-android --deviceId=f4e91c11):

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1567 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
'C:\Users\ASUS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error No Android device or emulator connected.


When using npm run android without specifying a device (multiple devices connected):
Error Logs:

> Task :app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Redmi Note 9 Pro Max - 12' for app:debug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_3a_API_33_x86_64(AVD) - 13' for app:debug
Installed on 2 devices.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6m 15s
537 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 529 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
adb.exe: error: more than one device/emulator
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": Command failed: C:\Users\ASUS LAPTOP-2\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
info Starting the app...
adb.exe: more than one device/emulator
error Failed to start the app.

Additional Context:
USB debugging is enabled on the device, and it is properly connected.
Paths in my environment variables that contain spaces are enclosed in double quotes.
I have restarted the adb server with adb kill-server and adb start-server, confirming the device is listed.
Questions:
How can I resolve the command prompt error that does not recognize paths containing spaces, particularly when starting the JS server in a React Native project?
What steps should I take to address the "No Android device or emulator connected" error when targeting a specific device (npx react-native run-android --deviceId=f4e91c11)?
How do I manage the "more than one device/emulator" error effectively when multiple devices are connected and I want to run the app without specifying a device?
I would appreciate any insights or guidance on these issues!
